# How to use cmake command in cmake source code

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am trying to get the binaries of the modules of cmake, but I am not able to do cmake in any of the folder even though a cmakeLists.txt is available. This is the error I am getting.

```
tusharecmc@tusharecmc-Aspire-E5-575:~/cmake3.10.2/src/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "FC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER to the full
  path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tusharecmc/cmake3.10.2/src/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tusharecmc/cmake3.10.2/src/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`
```

Comment: "No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found." - It wants Fortran compiler. Name of subdirectory `Modules/FortranCInterface/Verify` is definitely about Fortran.

Comment: No I just installed the fortran compiler and gave the path it worked

Comment: @tushar_ecmc you could set `-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=...` in the command line.